# Is there a way in Visual Studio 2019 to navigate to a header that isn't in the project files?

Tags: visual-studio, ide

I'm working on a project in C/C++ that has a custom build system that uses XML files to specify source files, and for development purposes the XML is used to generate Visual Studio project files (.vcxproj). Headers are not included in the VS project files (the include directories are populated, so the VS build works just fine). In Visual Studio 2013, I was able to navigate to headers with `ctrl + ,` but that often doesn't work in VS2019.

Is there a way to make VS2019 navigate to a file that isn't specified in any projects in the solution, but is included by files that are?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the answer was right under my nose: there's an option in the Go To menu (ctrl+,) for "Include contents of external items in search results". Enabling that option makes it behave as it did for me in VS2013.